# What is the relation between discontinuities and stiffness

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to understand the effect of introducing discontinuities inside ODE  on system stiffness.

simply speaking if we have an equation :

[image]

you can have further look here
https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html [Simple Event Location: A Bouncing Ball]

Now if we rewrite this equations as

[image]

do we expect that the stiffness of the problem becoming higher (of course from ODE solver prespective) means higher chance for numerical errors, especially at y= 0.

any thoughts ?

Comment: Is this a question about the software *Mathematica*? Or MATLAB? Or a general mathematics question? (This is a site for questions about how to use *Mathematica*.)

Comment: @Michael E2:  No... this is *not* "a site for questions about how to use Mathematica."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "This" = mathematiica.stackexchange.com, before the question was migrated, which is "a site for questions about how to use *Mathematica.*"